# How to modify values of multiple XML tags?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have been trying to modify values of more than one XML tag in java. So far I am able to get the values of the two nodes that I want to modify but while setting up values it always overrides the first one with the second one.

XML

```
 <driver>
    <BirthDate>1977-07-18</BirthDate>
    <Age>40</Age>                    
    <Gender>M</Gender>
    <PrimaryResidence>OwnCondo</PrimaryResidence>
 </driver>
```

I am trying to change Gender and PrimaryResidence tags.

Code

```
// Modifies multiple XML nodes
 public static String changeCoreDiscountType(String reqXML) {
        Document document = null;
        String updatedXML = null;
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(reqXML));
            document = builder.parse(is);

            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            XPathExpression expression = xPath.compile("/driver/Gender | /driver/PrimaryResidence");
            NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) expression.evaluate(document,XPathConstants.NODESET);

            for(int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                node.setTextContent("F");
                node.setTextContent("OwnCondo");
                String value = node.getTextContent();
            }

            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
            transformer.transform(source, result);

            updatedXML = result.getWriter().toString();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return updatedXML;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check you are updating the correct node first, e.g.

```
for(int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nodeList.item(i);

    if(node.getNodeName() == "Gender")
        node.setTextContent("F");
    if(node.getNodeName() == "PrimaryResidence")
        node.setTextContent("OwnCondo");
}
```

**[Full Demo](https://ideone.com/5G2IuE)**

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Cool. Thanks for it.